# How to select data from two entities in core data

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to select data from two entities in core data?
I mean i have two tables eg:Manager and UserInfo.I want to select all the Users who are users.So i need to join these two tables.  How?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a relationship. I suggest you follow this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: I gave you a tutorial. If you are writing an app, you might as well take 10 minutes and go through it. It's not a code snippet. It's done visually in the Core Data model.